# PHP Cookies and Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I'm pretty much into PHP right now and I am a bit perplexed with how to use a cookie to send a value to my next page.  The primary page will display results of a mysql query with a client's name in hyperlink.  When I click the link, it will pass me onto the next page that will enable me to edit the details of the certain client.

My question does sound super basic.  But this has stumped me for a couple days already.  have read through all the different documents about cookies and query strings and sessions, still to no avail.  If you guys can just point me in the right direction - a specific topic or document to read for the process I mentioned above, it would be much obliged.  Thanks in advance and pardon me for being such a noob.

Comment: Link can help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5876877/2689199)

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone through this simple documentation.Hope this will be helpful.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

To set the cookie value.

```
<?php
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", time()+3600);
?>
```

To retrieve the cookie value in the next page.

```
<?php
// Print a cookie
echo $_COOKIE["user"];

// A way to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Comment: Yes I have.  Just can't figure out how to set the value of the cookie into a variable depending on the query result from the previous page.

Comment: In the first page you may assign the value into the variable and in the next page try to retrieve the same value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

**syntax**

```
setcookie("cookie_name","cookie_value","expire time","path");
```

Here `path` and `expire time` are optional.

In the first page,create cookie using below code

Let `$value= Alex Porter`,then

```
setcookie("user", $value, time()+3600);
```

or

```
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", time()+3600);
```

Then in the second page,retrieve  the value of the cookie named user (ie Alex Porter) using

```
echo $_COOKIE['user'];
```

or

`$user= $_COOKIE['user'];`//assigning value to a variable